# Cocoapods Generated duplicate UUIDs

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Just reinstalled pod file "pod install"
And error appears

> [!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:
>
> PBXAggregateTarget -- 072CEA044D2EF26F03496D5996BBF59F
> PBXAggregateTarget -- 8D7F5D5DD528D21A72DC87ADA5B12E2D

What is it? And how to fix it?
(Xcode)